# Printing a list in python without printing the brackets

Tags: python, list

I currently am making a list in python and I would like to find out how I can print a list without printing the brackets.

I have tried using different techniques on W3schools but they don't work.

Here's my code...

```
import os
import time
list1 = [input("First item: "), input("Second item: "), 
input("Third item: ")]
time.sleep(0.5)
if (os.system == 'nt'):
  os.system("cls")
else:
  os.system("clear")
print(list1)
```

Comment: `print(*your_list)` to spread the list elements as args to print.  You can specify `sep` to change the separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `a= [1,2,3']`, then try:

`print(str(a).replace(']', "").replace('[', ""))`, whose output will be:
`1, 2, 3`